# Was Frodo's pity for Gollum caused by the Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Frodo grows to pity Gollum over time. Is this pity caused by the Ring, for its own purposes, or would Frodo have pitied Gollum even if he wasn't the Ring-Bearer?

Comment: *Into this Ring, he poured his compassion, his benevolence and his will to pity all life.*

Comment: Perhaps the wording could be improved, given the disagreements below. The question isn't really either/or: Frodo's pity was certainly not caused by the ring **for its own purposes**, but his experience with the ring gave him significant insight into what Smeagol had been through. I might suggest an edit when I am less tired.

Comment: @IanThompson I think the question here is _not_ whether the experience of bearing the load of the ring caused Frodo's pity.  The question is specifically asking if it was a magical effect of the ring to cause this pity "for its own purposes".

Comment: @IanThompson "Frodo's pity was certainly not caused by the ring for its own purposes" I wouldn't be so sure.  If Frodo doesn't pity Gollum and instead kills him, there is a greatly-reduced chance of conflict within the fellowship.  Keeping Gollum around may mean more opportunities for the ring to slip away or make Frodo get caught.  Sauron obviously doesn't pity Gollum, but that doesn't mean he wouldn't benefit from Frodo pitying him.

Comment: @Ryan_L --- It seems very unlikely that the ring could have devised a plan that relied on a concept totally alien to Sauron.

Comment: @GreenAsJade --- That may be so, and it's certainly the way I interpreted the question when I first read it. However, a lot of the discussion below focuses on the clause 'caused by the ring' rather than 'for its own purposes'.

Comment: @IanThompson do we actually know Sauron doesn't understand pity?  It seems possible to understand a perspective without sharing it.  I understand how bats use sonar to get around even though I can't.

Comment: @Ryan_L --- Sauron is defeated because he cannot understand his enemies' plan. As Gandalf puts it '... the only measure he knows is desire, desire for power; and so he judges all hearts'. Admittedly I can't find a direct quote relating to pity or mercy, but the idea that the ring could use such traits to its advantage seems highly unlikely to me.

Comment: @IanThompson I always thought that statement from Gandalf was saying that Sauron would have difficulty seeing past his biases, not that he was physically incapable of doing so.  Maybe this should be its own question, idk.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Was it caused by the Ring? Not really, but sort of.

Frodo is, by nature, a nice person. This is established as a basic fact of his personality, and that the Ring could get even *Frodo* of all people to lust for power (as shown right before it's destroyed in *The Return of the King*) is a testament to the Ring's sheer power.

It's worth keeping in mind, though, that Frodo didn't really meet Gollum until after Frodo had been the Ringbearer for a while. Frodo had presumably heard about Gollum from Bilbo's stories, and he obviously doesn't like him very much, as the quote that @DanielRoseman brings proves:

> “What a pity that Bilbo did not stab that vile creature, when he had a chance!”
>
> “Pity? It was Pity that stayed his hand. Pity, and Mercy: not to strike without need. And he has been well rewarded, Frodo. Be sure that he took so little hurt from the evil, and escaped in the end, because he began his ownership of the Ring so. With Pity.”

This conversation must have stuck in Frodo's head - after all, Gandalf was essentially telling him that Bilbo's pity for Gollum saved Bilbo from becoming just like Gollum.

And once Frodo actually meets Gollum, Frodo has been the Ringbearer for a while. He's had time to experience firsthand what the Ring does to you, and seen what it did to Bilbo (remember that scene in Rivendell?). Frodo can see just how Sméagol could have turned into Gollum, and how easy it would be for Frodo himself to follow the same path.

So yes - the Ring did indeed effect Frodo's pity for Gollum, because it allowed him to experience in part what Gollum was going through and how he wasn't all that different from Frodo himself.

Comment: I like this answer better because it touches on the empathy Frodo develops after holding the ring. I don't remember if it's in the book, but in the movie Frodo emphasizes that he has to know Gollum isn't beyond redemption.

Comment: Unfortunately the HNQ means the better answer has scored worse. This certainly the better answer and looks past a single quote and deeper into the story. Frodo's pity wasn't an effect of the ring directly, but his experience with the ring meant he could empathise with Smeagol and understood the struggle he went through.

Comment: @Edlothiad -- Yes, empathy was in part efficiently caused by Frodo's experience as a Ring Bearer (presumably in conjunction with his conversation with Gandalf in Moria) but in the final analysis it was Frodo's character that moved him to pity; or not, as we see highlighted in user287095's answer. -- Nothing good can come from the One Ring, no matter the wielder.

Comment: @user23715, even at the end Frodo still pities Smeagol in the way Bilbo pitied Gollum 60+ years earlier. He doesn't slay him but spares him and sends him away. Even at the brink, just before the end Frodo shows him pity. This is in part due to his character, but also as stated due to their connection/empathy through the ring.

Answer (score 84):

I can't think why you would say it would be caused by the Ring. On the contrary, it's made clear throughout that Frodo's - and Bilbo's before him - pity is what saves them. Remember Frodo's and Gandalf's conversation in A Shadow From The Past:

> “What a pity that Bilbo did not stab that vile creature, when he had a chance!”
>
> “Pity? It was Pity that stayed his hand. Pity, and Mercy: not to strike without need. And he has been well rewarded, Frodo. Be sure that he took so little hurt from the evil, and escaped in the end, because he began his ownership of the Ring so. With Pity.”

Comment: Agreed. Sauron doesn't really do pity, so why should the ring? On the other hand, Frodo shows mercy to Saruman and Grima after the destruction of the ring, so it's clearly in his nature.

Comment: Why the ring might cause Frodo to pity Gollum: I could imagine it thinking it has a better chance of getting back to Sauron if it was in Gollum's hands instead of Frodo's, and setting up an opportunity for Gollum to take it back by making Frodo feel empathy for him.

Comment: You seem to have completely missed the nail and hit your thumb. While your quote covers Bilbo's pity for Gollum it doesn't address Frodo in the slightest. The ring definitely affects Frodo's perception of Smeagol, and it changes as time with Smeagol and the ring. Not because the ring itself desires Frodo to pity Smeagol, but because Frodo can empathise with Smeagol's struggle without the ring and the effect it had on him.

Comment: @Edlothiad I think from context that while Gandalf is describing Bilbo's actions, he is also suggesting what everyone else -- including Frodo -- should act like. In the end, this "fate" that rewards pity rewards everyone on Middle Earth, by making sure Gollum is alive to accidentally destroy the Ring when Frodo couldn't summon the will.

Comment: Amazing that this got downvotes. Only on scifi.se, I guess, can someone be downvoted by answering politely with an actual reference that supports the answer.

Comment: @AndresF. I downvoted, because this answer is wrong. It says the ring had _nothing_ to do with Frodo's pity and it was purely what Gandalf said and Frodo's nature. However this isn't correct. The effect of the ring on Frodo had a drastic impact on his views of Smeagol.

Comment: @Edlothiad I think Gandalf implies it is fate and a "higher power", which is not the Ring, what is at play here. The same power that makes riddles and promises powerful in Middle Earth. Showing pity and mercy is valued by this higher power (which has more than one similarity  with Catholicism), and so people with a merciful nature (e.g. Bilbo, Frodo) are "rewarded". Note that little word, "rewarded" -- by what or whom? Certainly not the Ring.

Comment: @AndresF. - I'm not sure Eru intervenes that much...

Comment: @Mithical I don't think it's Eru either, except by its initial plan (or "song"). I think it's a higher power/fate that rewards goods deeds and punishes oathbreaking, to name some examples (there are more in the Middle Earth universe). In Tolkien's mind, probably the qualities of a good Catholic.

Comment: "I can't think why you would say it would be caused by the Ring. " is a needless and asinine remark. I think it's a very insightful, intelligent thought to consider that the ring - who always wants to get back to its master - would influence Frodo to keep Gollum around. Please don't disregard peoples' questions like that. I have no clue how your answer has gotten this far with such an insulting opening sentence.

Comment: @kwc --- I think it's unlikely that the ring could conceive a plan using a concept that is totally alien to Sauron.

Comment: It seems odd that the argument in this answer is that Frodo has compassion leading to pity, but the quote chosen is an example where Frodo has no compassion, and Gandalf has to correct him.

Comment: @AndresF. it seems you've got some misunderstandings regarding the way theology and "higher powers" and fate work in Middle-earth. Gandalf doesn't imply any of the sort. He simply states that sparing Gollum's life has proven beneficial. Especially when it comes to ownership of the Ring. Note Sam's harshness towards Gollum but his lack of pity towards him. He was never punished for not showing pity. Frodo shows absolutely 0 pity to begin with, yet should for some reason be rewarded? It is his time with the ring that leads him to pity Smeagol.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I think it's a teaching moment. Frodo has a lot of good in him, but he still has to learn and his initial reaction is immature -- kill the bad guy. This lesson on pity by Gandalf is one of the "big moments" in LotR's philosophy, and Frodo often acts in merciful ways afterwards. He just fails in the final moment, but I think that's expected too -- the burden was indeed too big for a single human (or Hobbit) to carry it for so long, and it's a testament to Frodo's fortitude that he lasted so long before fully succumbing to it.

Comment: Note a similar journey is depicted in Star Wars with Luke: Luke is fundamentally good, but must learn the power of mercy and restraint, and risks falling to evil. Just like Frodo.

Answer (score 11):

I think there is textual evidence that the Ring not only was not the cause of Frodo’s pity but actually worked to undermine it. As Frodo gets closer to Mt Doom his burden becomes heavier and the Ring’s influence over him grows stronger, until it finally overcomes his will to destroy it. Just before this, Gollum betrays Frodo, breaking his oath to serve the master of the Precious. From Sam’s perspective on pp. 922:

> Then suddenly, as before under the eaves of the Emyn Muil, Sam saw these two rivals with other vision. A crouching shape, scarcely more than the shadow of a living thing, a creature now wholly ruined and defeated, yet filled with a hideous lust and rage; and before it stood stern, untouchable now by pity, a figure robed in white, but at its breast it held a wheel of fire. Out of the fire spoke a commanding voice.
>
> ‘Begone and trouble me no more! If you touch me ever again, you shall be cast yourself into the Fire of Doom.’

Frodo’s pity (and Bilbo’s) is the only thing which has spared Smeagol’s life up until this point. But on the slopes of Mt Doom, Frodo has become untouchable by pity, and nothing is preventing the Ring from spelling out Gollum’s doom.

Comment: I don't see any textual evidence that the Ring causes Frodo's pity. None is provided in this answer. What the provided text shows is that Frodo's (well justified) warning to Gollum spells doom for both Gollum and the Ring. Gollum does touch him again (biting off the finger with the Ring on it) and in doing so falls into the fire Ring in hand. The implication is that Frodo's persistent pity---and the nobility and justice in his use of commanding might in this critical moment where he claims the Ring---is in fact what saves him and undoes the Ring. Why would the Ring cause that?

Answer (score 4):

No. Rather, it was the plain Hobbit goodness that Gandalf saw in the Bagginses (indeed in all the Shire).

> 'there is a kind of power in the Shire, too'
> ~*Gandalf*

Although, yes, Frodo does identify himself with Gollum due to their shared relationship with the Ring and this affords Frodo great sympathy with him.